# When using alias containing cd and echos, an arrow appear but nothing else

Tags: bash

I made a pretty long alias and I can't get it to work. I put it in ~/.bash_profile. Here is it:

```
alias venga='cd ~/Users/clem/Desktop/venga/ ; echo "Vous êtes dans le dossier venga de votre site web." ; echo " " ; echo "Pour ajouter un commit, utilisez :" ; echo "git commitcommit -am "Message du Commit" ; echo " " ; echo "Pour envoyer le dossier vers GitHub, utilisez :" ; echo "git push origin master" ; echo " " ; echo "Pour ajouter un fichier à git utilisez :" ; echo "git add nomdufichier.xx"'
```

Here's the output:

```
$ venga
>
```

When I hit enter, other arrows appear below. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I would probably create a function instead of an alias.  Much easier to edit later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unclosed quote, due to the unescaped quote in:

```
echo "git commitcommit -am "Message du Commit" ;
```

The `>` is a continuation prompt, because the shell is waiting for you to close the quote. You don't need an alias to see this happening:

```
$ echo "Hello
>
>
> world"
Hello


world
$
```

You probably intended to have:

```
echo "git commit -am \"Message du Commit\""
```

... or ...

```
echo 'git commit -am "Message du Commit"'
```

But quoting in the shell is a bit of a minefield at the best of times.

A cleaner way of outputting many lines to stdout is `cat` with a here document:

```
 cat << END
 Hello
 "World"
 DONE
```

Comment: Not sure I agree with the minefield characterization -- the rules one needs to follow are very well-defined. *Not* following those rules puts one in a minefield, to be sure... but let's say that it's a minefield that comes with a map, and it's only folks who think they know better than that map who get into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Write this as a function, not an alias:

```
venga() {
  cd /Users/clem/Desktop/venga/ || {
    echo "Impossible d'accéder au répertoire du site Web"
    return
  }
  echo 'Vous êtes dans le dossier venga de votre site web.'
  echo
  echo 'Pour ajouter un commit, utilisez :'
  echo 'git commitcommit -am "Message du Commit"'
  echo 
  echo 'Pour envoyer le dossier vers GitHub, utilisez :'
  echo 'git push origin master'
  echo
  echo 'Pour ajouter un fichier à git utilisez :'
  echo 'git add nomdufichier.xx'
}
```

Allows error handling, makes the code much easier to read -- and moots the quoting concerns that caused you trouble with the alias form.

(I also fixed up `~/Users/clem/Desktop/venga` to `/Users/clem/Desktop/venga`, as the former was looking for something like `$HOME/Users/clem/Desktop/venga`, and you probably don't have `Users` *under* `$HOME`).

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched ".

I think the guilty part is:

`echo "git commitcommit -am "Message du Commit"`

Here's the fixed version:

`alias venga='cd ~/Users/clem/Desktop/venga/ ; echo "Vous êtes dans le dossier venga de votre site web." ; echo " " ; echo "Pour ajouter un commit, utilisez :" ; echo "git commitcommit -am \"Message du Commit\"" ; echo " " ; echo "Pour envoyer le dossier vers GitHub, utilisez :" ; echo "git push origin master" ; echo " " ; echo "Pour ajouter un fichier à git utilisez :" ; echo "git add nomdufichier.xx"'`

Also you'll probably be better off putting this instructions in a separate file, that you just `cat`, rather than having a number of echos.